# SQL History Traversal Table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table t

```
Current  History  Result
-------------------------
  5        6      black
  6        4      White
  4        1      Black
```

With a number of 5, how do I traverse back in history 2 times to derive the result to be black or white?

```
5 -> 6 -> 4 -> black
```

Assuming there are other rows of data in the table as well.

I have tried:

```
select *
from t.result
where t.current in t.history 
  and t.current in t.history where t.current in ('5')
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You have tagged three...

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of entries? If no limit look at `recursive CTE`. Edit the tags to limit to a single DBMS first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requirement is upto 2 level, you can try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3da2645c12e3b3bd3efcdd705792ac56)

```
SELECT A.[Current],A.History,C.[Current],C.Result 
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.History = B.[Current]
INNER JOIN your_table C ON B.History = C.[Current]
WHERE  A.[Current] IN (5)
```